# Rails namespace routes and custom action on resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, routes

I currently have these routes set up:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users do
      match 'api/v1/users/all'
    end
    resources :sessions
  end
end
```

I'm trying to set up a custom actio nin my users controller called "all".

How do I get the route for that to match? I've tried these, and get no route errors:

```
resources :users do
  match 'api/v1/users/all' => "users#all" (also "api/v1/users#all" and "api_v1_users#all"
end
```

What is the route that will enable me to connect with my custom action?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `collection`

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users do
      collection do
        get 'all'
      end
    end
    resources :sessions
  end
end
```

The `namespace` and `resources` method calls create the hierarchy; a route nested with the `resource :users` block will take on the path of it's ancestors. The `collection` creates nested routes on the resource collection instead of single instances of the resource.

```
/api/v1/users/all
```

Recommended Reading: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes